# Sql aggregate function to obtain a list

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions

Hei!

How can I create an aggregate function to obtain a list of the aggregate values.

given :

```
key     value
Andrei  1
Andrei  2
Andrei  3
Mihai   4
Mihai   5
Mihai   6
```

I want

```
key list
Andrei 1,2,3
Mihai 4,5,6
```

Comment: I used this article once to to the exact same thing: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS SQL solution:
[Note: This solution only works on SQL 2005 and later. Original question didn't specify the version in use.]

```
SELECT 
key
, STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST([value] AS nvarchar(max)) FROM <#Table#> WHERE (key = Results.key) FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'') AS NameValues
FROM <#Table#> Results
GROUP BY key
```

Comment: and the nice thing about that solution is that it doesn't blow up if you have invalid xml characters in your substrings.. oh whoops, yes it does.

Comment: as far as I see value is just int, so that won't be an issue

Comment: I prefer to solve the problem when it comes, rather than write gigs generic solutions to fit all the future and possible requirements.

Comment: My point is why choose the cute solution that fails in a hard to detect way (I know this because someone was telling me what a cute solution this was and then I had to rewrite it because it failed in a complex way) when you can use something not so cute that works across the board.

Answer (score 2):

**For those that want to do this in 2022:**

I do this

```sql
select [Key], STRING_AGG([Value], ',') as [List]
from TableX
group by [Key]
```

In my case [Value] is a string, but if it's an int you can first cast it to a string. The ',' is to indicate my chosen separator.
Works on Azure SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to simulate group_concat function of MySQL.

Check [this article](http://explainextended.com/2010/06/21/group_concat-in-sql-server/) for more info.