# Is there a way to reduce redundant fields in an SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am just getting into SQL server, and I have built the following test database.

The DB has 4 entities: MC (place of employement), users, classes, and completed classes.  The purpose is to track employees that take training courses for their respective MC (market center).  I decided to recently add on the completed classes table to help normalize the DB.  Here is the code I have thus far.

"

```
--CREATE CLASS TABLE BELOW

CREATE TABLE classes
(class_id INT CONSTRAINT class_class_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
class_name VARCHAR (30) CONSTRAINT class_class_name_nn NOT NULL,
class_address VARCHAR (40),
class_city VARCHAR (20),
class_state VARCHAR (30),
class_instructor VARCHAR (25));

--CREATE USER TABLE BELOW

CREATE TABLE users
(users_id INT CONSTRAINT users_users_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
u_username VARCHAR (30) CONSTRAINT users_u_username_nn NOT NULL,
u_LastName VARCHAR (30),
u_FirstName VARCHAR (25),
u_password VARCHAR (20),
u_authentication CHAR (1));

--CREATE COMPLETED CLASS TABLE BELOW

CREATE TABLE completed
(complete_id INT CONSTRAINT completed_complete_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
complete_class_id INT CONSTRAINT completed_complete_class_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (complete_class_id)
REFERENCES classes (class_id) ,
complete_user_id INT CONSTRAINT completed_complete_user_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (complete_user_id)
REFERENCES users (users_id));

--CREATE MARKET CENTER TABLE BELOW

CREATE TABLE marketcenter
(mc_id INT CONSTRAINT marketcenter_mc_id_pk PRIMARY KEY,
mc_name VARCHAR (40) CONSTRAINT marketcenter_mc_name_nn NOT NULL,
mc_poc VARCHAR (30));

--ALTER STATEMENT / FOREIGN KEY IMPLEMENTATION

ALTER TABLE users
ADD u_class_id INT;

ALTER TABLE users
ADD u_mc_id INT;

ALTER TABLE users
ADD CONSTRAINT users_u_class_id_fk  FOREIGN KEY (u_class_id)
REFERENCES classes (class_id);

ALTER TABLE users
ADD CONSTRAINT users_u_mc_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (u_mc_id)
REFERENCES marketcenter (mc_id);

"

Never mind the specifics, the tables were built up just fine (i think).  My problem is when I run a query. For example:

SELECT u_FirstName, u_LastName, mc_name, class_name
 FROM users, marketcenter, completed, classes
 WHERE complete_class_id = class_id
 AND u_mc_id = mc_id
 AND complete_user_id = users_id
 ORDER BY mc_name;
```

The query gives me all the information I want, however there is too much redundancy.  Essentially I want to display what students have taken which class.  Obviously students have taken more than one class, but I dont need it to tell me the students name for each instance of the completed classes.

**I want it to look something like this:**

**Student: John Doe, East MC, Classes 1, 3, 4, 5**

**Instead of :**

**Student: John Doe, East MC, Classes 1**

**Student: John Doe, East MC, Classes 3**

**Student: John Doe, East MC, Classes 4**

**Student: John Doe, East MC, classes 5**

I hope this makes sense.  Is there a way in MS Sql Server to display it like this?  Im still pretty new at all of this so thanks for the assistance in advance.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358691/sql-aggregate-function-to-obtain-a-list

Comment: *Side note:* As you are new to SQL, try to **NOT** to use implicit `JOIN`

Comment: I will heed your advice.  I still dont understand the differences between joins but Im currently at this point in my sql journey.  Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Let's add some sample data for different classes/users/completed (I ignored mark center for simplicity).

```
   INSERT INTO Classes VALUES 
 (1, 'AA', 'AAAA', 'AAAA','AAAA','AAAAA'),
 (2, 'BB', 'BBBB', 'BBBB','BBBB','BBBB')

 INSERT INTO users (USERS_ID,U_USERNAME, u_LastName, u_FirstName) VALUES
 (11,'abc', 'ab', 'cd'),
 (22, 'efg','ef','gh')

INSERT INTO Completed VALUES
(1, 1, 11),
(2, 2, 11)
```

Then you might use this query

```
SELECT urs2.u_FirstName,
       urs2.u_LastName,
         (STUFF((SELECT CAST(', '  + cls.class_name AS varchar(MAX))
         FROM classes cls INNER JOIN completed comp on cls.class_id = comp.complete_class_id 
              INNER JOIN users urs ON comp.complete_user_id = urs.users_id

         where  comp.complete_class_id is not null and urs.users_id = urs2.users_id
         for XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')) AS Classes
from users urs2
```

and the output would be something like this

```
  u_Firstname u_LastName   Classes
    cd         ab          AA, BB
    gh         ef          NULL
```

Please note that if you want to use class id rather than class name, then you need to use `concat` function like this

```
SELECT urs2.u_FirstName,
       urs2.u_LastName,
         (STUFF((SELECT CAST(concat(', '  , cls.class_id) AS varchar(MAX))
         FROM classes cls INNER JOIN completed comp on cls.class_id = comp.complete_class_id 
              INNER JOIN users urs ON comp.complete_user_id = urs.users_id

         where  comp.complete_class_id is not null and urs.users_id = urs2.users_id
         for XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')) AS Classes
from users urs2
```

Comment: Thanks for all of the advice.  Im going to sit with all of this and see if I can get the results I want.  Ill check back but again, thanks!

Comment: I have one question however.  I hope you can answer this or atleast point me into the right direction so I can understand this on my own time.  

Where did you get "usrs2."  and "cls."  and "comp."?  Is there a specific topic of SQL that can explain these better?  Sorry but ive only been at this for 2 weeks. LOL.

Comment: @Big_dog_floppy those are called aliases in sql server. Those are the tables that you have with an alternative name per say. So when I say users urs then I am using the alias urs to represent the table users. You could only use users instead of using aliases. If the query gives you the desired answer, please mark it as an answer. Thanks