# SQL server - Pivot only on a part of the result

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, pivot, partial

I need to put columns in rows only for the last columns of my query's results.

The query is :

```
select 
     dpp.CODE_PORTEFEUILLE,
     dpr.SOCIETE_GESTION,
     lgp.CODE_GERANT,
     lgp.DEVISE_GERANT,
     lgp.CODE_INTERVENANT
from 
     GP3DBA.DESCRIPTIF_PORTEFEUILLE dpp  
          join GP3DBA.DESCRIPTIF_PORT_REPORTING dpr on dpp.CODE_PORTEFEUILLE = dpr.CODE_PORTEFEUILLE  
          join GP3DBA.LIEN_GERANT_PORTEFEUILLE lgp  on dpp.CODE_PORTEFEUILLE = lgp.CODE_PORTEFEUILLE
```

RESULT:
[image]

DESIRED RESULT:
[image]

I have tried to do it myself, but without any satisfying result.

Comment: It's better to include all of the information in the question itself and avoid screenshots. Most the people won't bother to look at them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql aggregate function to obtain a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358691/sql-aggregate-function-to-obtain-a-list)

Comment: Dynamic SQL is not far from what I suggested

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT**

I don't see an easy way to do this. 
You actual result is in #tmpResult in this example.

```
select CODE_PORTEFEUILLE, SOCIETE_GESTION, count(1) as 'number'
into #columnNumber
from #tmpResult
group by CODE_PORTEFEUILLE, SOCIETE_GESTION

declare @columnMaxNumber int;

SELECT @columnMaxNumber = MAX(number) 
FROM #columnNumber

declare @tableSql = 'CREATE TABLE #finalResult( 
    CODE_PORTEFEUILLE int not null, 
    SOCIETE_GESTION varchar(10) not null'

declare @cnt int = 0;
WHILE @cnt < @columnMaxNumber 
BEGIN
   set @tableSql = @tableSql + ', CODE_GERANT' + @cnt + ' varchar(2)' 
   set @tableSql = @tableSql + ', DEVISE_GERANT' + @cnt + ' varchar(3)'
   set @tableSql = @tableSql + ', CODE_INTERVENANT' + @cnt + ' varchar(3)'
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END

set @tableSql = @tableSql + ')'

exec @tableSql
```

then you just have to inject data in this table

```
declare cursor_portefeuille CURSOR FOR
select * from #tmpResult /*order by fields you want to order by*/

declare @code_portefeuille int, @societe_gestion varchar(3), @code_gerant varchar(2), @device_gerant varchar(3), @code_intervenant varchar(3), @gerant_index int = 0, @last_portefeuille int = 0, @last_societe varchar(3) = ''


OPEN cursor_portefeuille 

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_portefeuille 
INTO @code_portefeuille, @societe_gestion, @code_gerant, @device_gerant, @code_intervenant

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    if(@last_portefeuille = @code_portefeuille and @last_societe = @societe_gestion)
    begin
        set @gerant_index = @gerant_index + 1
    end
    else
    begin
        set @last_portefeuille = @code_portefeuille
        set @last_societe = @societe_gestion
        set @gerant_index = 0
    end
    if exists(select 1 from #finalResult where CODE_PORTEFEUILLE = @code_portefeuille and SOCIETE_GESTION = @societe_gestion)
    begin
        declare @sqlQuery varchar(512) = 'update #finalResult
        set CODE_GERANT' + @gerant_index + ' = @code_gerant,
        DEVISE_GERANT' + @gerant_index + ' = @device_gerant,
        CODE_INTERVENANT' + @gerant_index + ' = @code_intervenant
        WHERE CODE_PORTEFEUILLE = @code_portefeuille and SOCIETE_GESTION = @societe_gestion'
        exec @sqlQuery;
    end
    else
    begin
         insert into #finalResult(CODE_PORTEFEUILLE, SOCIETE_GESTION, CODE_GERANT0, DEVISE_GERANT0, CODE_INTERVENANT0)
         values(@code_portefeuille, @societe_gestion, @code_gerant, @device_gerant, @code_intervenant)
    end
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_portefeuille 
    INTO @code_portefeuille, @societe_gestion, @code_gerant, @device_gerant, @code_intervenant
END
CLOSE cursor_portefeuille ;  
DEALLOCATE cursor_portefeuille ; 

SELECT * from #finalResult

/*Don't forget to drop temp tables */
```

Didn't try it, I have no actual case at reach but I know the logic works.
But you should avoid doing this... It runs fairly slowly

Comment: Thai a lot to you all!

Comment: ? i don't understand what you're trying to say :) (essaie en français :P)

Comment: Is this the answer you were looking for ? if yes, tag it !