# In SqlServer, how to join a single column from multiple rows into a single row with multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In SqlServer 2008, I have a table like this:

```
+--------+--------------------+--------------+
some_key | some_discriminator | some_column
-------- | ------------------ | -------------
K1       | D1                 | V1
K1       | D2                 | V2
K2       | D1                 | V3
K2       | D2                 | V4
```

and I'd like to run a query that produces this:

```
+--------+------+--------
some_key |D1    | D2
---------|---------------
K1       | V1   | V2
K2       | V3   | V4
```

Comment: you can find part of the answer in this post => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39390972/sql-server-pivot-only-on-a-part-of-the-result/39392731#39392731

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple pivot query might suit your needs:

```
SELECT some_key,
       MAX(CASE WHEN some_discriminator = 'D1' THEN some_column ELSE NULL END) AS D1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN some_discriminator = 'D2' THEN some_column ELSE NULL END) AS D2
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY some_key
```

The grouping works because `MAX` ignores `NULL` values and `MAX` of a single `VARCHAR` returns that string.

But this might not be suitable if you have many columns, or dynamic columns, which you want to appear in the pivoted result.

Comment: Thanks for the response Tim. I should have mentioned the column types. The some_column contains varchars. I'm getting an error because the SUM operator is not expecting a varchar.

Comment: @KevinStembridge Sorry, I should have used `MAX` instead of `SUM`.