# Query for grouping Details with a name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to group a bunch of data by the company name with all unique data for that company after it

## Example table

```
Company name   Company Address   Order Number
Company 1        Address 1         0001
Company 1        Address 1         0002
Company 2        Address 2         0003
Company 2        Address 2         0004
Company 3        Address 3         0005
```

**What i would like is for the output to be like this**

```
Company name     Company Address   orders
Company 1        Address 1         0001,002
Company 2        Address 3         0003,004
Company 3        Address 3         0005
```

Comment: Oh dear...forgot I have gold on SQL tag.  If you can't figure it out using the duplicate link, drop a comment and someone will reopen.

Comment: Please refer.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358691/sql-aggregate-function-to-obtain-a-list